# Delphi function to C#

Tags: c#, delphi

I’m trying to convert this Delphi code to C#

```
function TWebModule1.DecodeA(Auth: string): Word;
var
  iAuth: Cardinal;
  r: Cardinal;
begin
  iAuth := StrToInt64(Auth);
  r := (iAuth and $FFFF0000) shr 16;
  Result := (iAuth and $FFFF) xor r xor $9752;
end;
```

Here is what I have written in C# but it’s not giving me the expected results.

```
private Int64 DecodeA(Int64 auth)
{
    try
    {
        var r = (auth & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16;
        var result = (auth & 0xFFFF) ^ r ^ 0x9752;
        _log.DebugFormat("Decoding of {0} returned {1}", auth, result);
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.Fatal(ex);
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Example:auth = 3216841950 should have a result of 41022

Thank you for any information you provide.

Comment: Can you debug both, breaking each individual calculation down to see where the C# code differs from the delphi?  That probably would be the fastest way

Comment: Delphi function uses Cardinal (LongWord), C# function uses Int64. It is possible that the number will be out of range. Use Int64/LongWord in both examples and test again. Why the Delphi function (which I suppose should work) returns 13361 on my computer instead of 41022? Are you sure that it is correct?

Comment: Your expected result is wrong.  The delphi code should be error checking for values out of bounds - `Cardinal` is an unsigned 32-bit type so there is a risk of wrap-around.  Your c# code should also use that type (and error check).  That notwithstanding, both pieces of code produce the same output for the input value of `3216841950`.  Your premise that the delphi code will return `41022` is wrong.

Comment: And it is a good idea to go easy on the `var` with this kind of code.

Comment: @J... there's no overflow here

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Perhaps more correct to say that there is potential overflow, but looking at it now, since only the lower 32-bits are masked and used, it does not affect the result.

Comment: @J... Potential only if the code is changed. And in fact all the operations happen in the low 16 bits.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The upper 16 bits of `iAuth` are also used.  In any case, I agree - I was hasty in my reaction.  I saw an `Int64` assigned to a `Cardinal` and my type-safety sensors went off like fireworks.  Upon closer inspection, in this instance, there seems no cause for alarm.

Comment: @J... Upper 16 bits shifted down and then everything else down in unsigned 16 bit land. The Int64 is just to cope with the absence of StrToCard.

Comment: @Yes, I understand, and in this case it is fine.  *In general*, however, assigning an Int64 to a cardinal is not guaranteed to not cause a loss of information.  It is unfortunate that there is no `StringToCard`, but if it did exist we would expect it to throw exceptions in all the cases where the string represents a number greater than `High(cardinal)` and less than `Low(cardinal)`.  At very least it would be nice to be explicit here with `iauth := Cardinal(StrToInt64(Auth) and $FFFFFFFF);`.  Syntactically unnecessary, but adds to readability and intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the same datatypes in both languages then it works just out of the box:

**Delphi version**

```
function DecodeA(iAuth: Int64): Int64;
var
  r: Int64;
begin
  r := (iAuth and $FFFF0000) shr 16;
  Result := (iAuth and $FFFF) xor r xor $9752;
end;
```

**C# version**

```
private Int64 DecodeA(Int64 iAuth)
{
    Int64 r = (iAuth & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16;
    return (iAuth & 0xFFFF) ^ r ^ 0x9752;       
}
```

In both languages DecodeA(3216841950) equals 13361

Comment: I don't know why you chose to use signed 64 bit integers for the operations. The Delphi code uses unsigned 32 bit integers. And I don't know why you chose to return a signed 64 bit integer. The Delphi code returns a unsigned 16 bit value.

Answer (score 1):

The key understanding this it to know why the Delphi developer chose to use `StrToInt64` considering that the rest of the code operates on 32 bit integers. The reason for this is that `StrToInt` returns a signed 32 bit integer, and so for values in the range `2^31` to `2^32 - 1` results in an error. The developer of the original Delphi code handled this by treating the input as a 64 bit integer, a data type that includes the complete range of a 32 bit unsigned type.

Now, in your C# code you can translate it very literally, but you don't need to use 64 bit types, just as the Delphi code does not. The Delphi code operates on 32 bit unsigned integers, and returns a 16 bit unsigned integer.

```
ushort DecodeA(uint iauth)
{
    uint r = (iauth & 0xffff0000) >> 16;
    return (ushort) (iauth & 0xffff) ^ r ^ 0x9752;
}

ushort DecodeA(string auth)
{
    return DecodeA(uint.Parse(auth));
}
```

Here I have provided two overloads, one for string input which parses the string, and one receives an unsigned 32 bit integer as input. The former calls the latter.

Note that I have followed the lead of the Delphi code and returned a 16 bit unsigned integer, `ushort`.